# Why is $2Re\{c_n e^{\frac{j2n\pi t}{T}} \}$ equal to $2Re\{c_n \} cos{\frac{2n\pi t}{T}} - 2Im \{ c_n \} sin{ \frac{2n\pi t}{T}} $?

Tags: fourier-series

Why is $2Re\{c_n e^{\frac{j2n\pi t}{T}} \}$ equal to $2Re\{c_n \} cos{\frac{2n\pi t}{T}} - 2Im \{ c_n \} sin{ \frac{2n\pi t}{T}}  $ in the Fourier series?

See images below:

[$C_n$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jB3U.png)

[Derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAu1g.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a complex number $z$ you can write it as $\Re(z)+i\Im(z)$ where $\Re$ and $\Im$ are the real and imaginary functions and **return purely real values**.

So consider the product of two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$:

$z_1\cdot z_2=(\Re(z_1)+i\Im(z_1))(\Re(z_2)+i\Im(z_2))$

$z_1\cdot z_2=(\Re(z_1)\Re(z_2)-\Im(z_1\Im(z_2))+i(\Re(z_1)\Im(z_2)+\Re(z_2)\Im(z_1))$

So $\Re(z_1\cdot z_2)=\Re(z_1)\Re(z_2)-\Im(z_1)\Im(z_2)$

Apply this to your situation: $c_n e^\frac{j2n\pi t}{T}$

$z_1=c_n$ and $z_2=e^\frac{j2n\pi t}{T}$

The real and imaginary functions applied to $e^{i\theta}$ gives $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ respectively. This leads to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary, 
consider to complex numbers a and b,
$$ 
a = a_1+i*a_2\ and\ b = b_1+i*b_2
$$
$$
Re(a*b) = Re((a_1+i a_2)*(b_1+i*b_2)) = Re((a_1*b_1-a_2*b_2)+i*(a_1*b_2+a_2*b_1)) = a_1*b_1-a_2*b_2 = Re(a)*Re(b)-Im(a)*Im(b)
$$
S0 if you consider $C_n$ as complex number
$$
Re(C_n*e^{j2n\pi t/T}) = Re(C_n)*Re(e^{j2n\pi t/T}) - Im(C_n)*Im(e^{j2n\pi t/T}) = Re(C_n)*cos(j2n\pi t/T) - Im(C_n)*sin(j2n\pi t/T)
$$